# Google Credential Provider for Windows (GCPW) seems to be interfering with Windows Hello (PIN and Fingerprint/Biometrics)

Tags: windows, g-suite

I'm trying to lock down everything in my company so that everybody uses Google Workspaces to log in to their machines. I've installed GCPW on my machine to test it out.

Since I've installed GCPW, every day or two, both my fingerprint scanner and Windows Hello PIN stop working. When I reboot my machine everything is fine (the same PIN and fingerprint scanner work great, no need to reset anything). I've tried deleting the `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Ngc` directory but that doesn't help. Another clue is that when either the fingerprint or Windows Hello PIN stops working, the other one doesn't work either. It's like some process disabled all of Windows Hello.

When I use the fingerprint scanner, I get the generic error: `Something went wrong. Please try again.`

When I try to use my Windows Hello PIN, I get the following error: `Something went wrong and your PIN isn't available (code: 0x80280013). Restart your device to see if that fixes the problem.`

Of course, rebooting does fix the problem but it's really annoying to reboot my computer every day. I can also use my Google Workspaces password to log in, but that takes a long time, especially to unlock my password manager, etc.

Has anybody else experienced this? Any idea how I can fix it?